# Why is the complement of a regular language still a regular language?

Tags: computer-science, discrete-mathematics, regular-language, formal-languages

According to my textbook, the complement of L1 = A* - L1 is a regular language as long as L1 is a regular language.
Doesn't A* also include Context Free languages, Context Sensitive languages, and Recursively Enumerable languages? A*-L1 would include all of them too, wouldn't it? How can it be regular then?
Under the representation of a Finite State Machine I understand why the complement is still a regular language. However, I can't understand the theory behind it.

Also, A* - L1 = A* intersection complement(L1) . Isn't defining a complement with something defined by the complement a tautology? I don't really understand how that can be valid.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your textbook not define A as a regular language?

Comment: Not only is `A` (the alphabet) regular (which is obvious because it is finite), but `A*` (the set of all possible strings) is regular too.  That might highlight the point of the question even better.  The accepts-everything machine accepts `A*` so regular-ness is not a property of the size of the language, but rather of its structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think where you are confused is that when you say "Doesn't `A*` also include Context Free languages, Context Sensitive languages, and Recursively Enumerable languages?" you are confusing `A*`, which is **a set of strings**, with `Powerset(A*)`, which is **a set of languages**.

It is true that `Powerset(A*) - {L1}` is a set containing "Context Free languages, Context Sensitive languages, and Recursively Enumerable languages" but it actually isn't relevant to the theorem which just says: given any regular language `L` (a set of strings), then the language `A*-L`, also *a set of strings*, is also a regular language.

TL;DR there's a confusion between levels in your question: sets of strings vs. sets of languages.  Any two-partition of `A*` into `L` and `A*-L` in which `L` is regular must also have `A*-L` regular.  `A*` does not and cannot "contain languages" because it is a set of strings.

To your second question:

> Also, A* - L1 = A* intersection complement(L1) . Isn't defining a complement with something defined by the complement a tautology?

Nice question.  I suspect if this is presented as a definition, that is just defining operator `-`.  It is not defining the "complement function" as far as I can tell.  Perhaps "complement" was already defined, and your book is now trying to define the subtraction operator.  Or else this is a theorem rather than a definition.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find my copy of [Hopcroft & Ullman](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc.html), but I think I found the correct definition for the complement of a regular language [here](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/regular/fa/complement.html). It *seems* correct and more conversationally clear to say that the complement of L is a DFA that accepts any string *except* those that are a member of L. So you move the accepting state to all (formerly) non-accepting states and your are done. Since the complement is just a permutation of the DFA, the result is still a DFA.

As far as the notation goes, I think you are reading it as `L1 = A* - L1` when it should be properly read as `complement L1 = A* - L1` where `complement` is the complement operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you can understand the automaton proof, then you have it all. The intuition behind it is that if you can recognize a regular language by running an automaton and seeing if it stops on a final state, then you can recognize the complement of that language (over the set of all strings) just by running the same automaton and seeing if stops on a non-final state. Since all strings stop on some state, and a language is regular if and only if it stops on a final state, then it is non-regular if and only if it stops on a non-final state. It's pretty intuitive, I guess. Also, the only thing you need to prove to yourself that a language is regular, is building an automaton for it: just swap all final and non-final states.