# Is this language regular

Tags: regular-language, formal-languages

Given **R** a **regular language**.

Is the following language also regular:

```
Comp(R) = { u | u is NOT a sub-word of a word in R }
```

It looks like there are no words in `Comp(R)` since there can not be any sub-word of word in `R`. 
But I might get it wrong. any suggestions?

Comment: Yes Regular, you can - draw DFA for Comp(R) as: **Step-1)** mark all stats as final state in DFA of R, **Step-2)** [find complement DFA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802732/finding-the-complement-of-a-dfa/14817545#14817545)

Comment: *`It looks like there are no words in Comp(R) since there can not be any sub-word of word in R`* ?? what do you means by sub-words in R?

Comment: Rouki Re-writing steps: (assuming you don't have dead states in DFA of R, and this is always possible) **step-1)**  mark all stats as final states **step-2)** mark all states as initial states (not you got an NFA) **step-3)** Convert NFA into DFA  **step-4)** Complement new DFA -- you  will get DFA for comp(R)!!

Answer (score 1):

The two following theorems implies that the answer is yes:

- The complement of a regular langage is regular: see [Why is the complement of a regular language still a regular language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936994/why-is-the-complement-of-a-regular-language-still-a-regular-language)
- The language of all the subword of a regulare langage is regular (double all transitions by epsilon transitions)

Comment: I difficulty is OP saying `any sub-word`,  but not all possible  prefixes.. that the reason I didn't posted an answer. but +1 as indeed it is a regular.